# Understanding Java Generic Types

Tags: java, generics

Consider this Generics Code:

```
interface Collection<E>  {  
   public void add (E x);  
   public Iterator<E> iterator(); 
}
```

And this one:

```
public class MyClass<V> {
    V v;
    setSomeValue(V val) {
       v=val;
    }

    V getSomeValue() {
        return v;
    }
 }
```

My Question:
Do those letters in angular brackets:
      `<V>` and `<E>` 
have specific meaning. 
Can i use any English Alphabet. i.e can they be 
     `<A>` or `<Q>`?

Comment: Yeah. You can use any English alphabet there.. But they have to be consistent..

Comment: You probably meant `return value` and `value = val`

Comment: Rohit, If that is the case why does this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html talk about using specific "Type Parameter Naming Conventions":

Comment: Because it is a convention, not a syntactic rule. There are also variable naming convetions. You should adopt them, but you're not forced to do so. You can make your code as well pretty unreadable if you absolutely want to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They do have to be valid Java identifiers (not necessarily just single letters as pointed out in the comment,) technically you can use any identifier that you like and your code will compile and run fine (if there are no other errors of course!)

It's good to stick to convention though - this tends to be single capital letters. Some common ones are `E`, `T`, `K` and `V`, standing for element, type, key and value respectively - your use case may well fit into one of those categories, in which case I'd use those letters. In the case of the above example, the `Collection` class uses `E` because it contains elements.

Comment: This link says that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html use K for Key, T for Type and so on.. so i am assuming its not forced.. just a convention.

Comment: @Jasper Correct, that's what I was trying to say :)

Comment: They do not have to be single letters. You can use anything that's a valid name in Java. That single letters are used is just a convention.

Answer (score 1):

```
interface Collection<E>  {  
   public void add (E x);  
   public Iterator<E> iterator(); 
}
```

Defining an interface like this means that you are telling compiler that, you can create a reference of this interface of any type... But, you have to use just `letters` to indicate generic type..

Ideally it is not a constraint that you should use only **`T, E, or V`**.. You can use any of them.. But, your code is more readable if you follow certain **conventions**..

`K - Key, V - Value`.. Like this..

So, the references for your above interface can be:  -

```
Collection<String>, Collection<Integer>, Collection<YourCustomObject>
```

And whatever type you use, that will automatically get reflected in your `method return types` and `parameters`..

So, for `Collection<String>`, your method would look like this: -]

```
   public void add (String x);  
   public Iterator<String> iterator();
```

Comment: They do not have to be single, upper-case letters; that's just a convention. You can use anything that's a valid identifier in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think they have to be letters. They are basically placeholders for class names. So if you wanted to instantiate MyClass you could do

```
new MyClass<String>();
```

This will replace all V in your code with String.

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) lesson has more details on generics

To quote this lesson

> The most commonly used type parameter names are:

```
E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
K - Key
N - Number
T - Type
V - Value
S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types
```

Comment: They do not have to be single, upper-case letters; that's just a convention.

Answer (score 0):

Usually they do but the compiler let's you name them as you want; as any other type since it  represents a generic name for a type.

The convention is:

T - type; most used in custom classes

E - element; used in collection

K - key; used in map

V - value; used in map

Answer (score 0):

Those `E` or `V` or whatever are just variables. They just suggest that the type is unknown at the time of writing the code. This also simplifies the job by using the same class for so many types of objects.

These can be understood from [`http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

```
The most commonly used type parameter names are:
    E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
    K - Key
    N - Number
    T - Type
    V - Value
    S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types
```

They are else can be defined as `wildcards` in java. These generics are mostly used to make a single class which is applicable for many `types` without requiring `casting`.

Answer (score 0):

The `E`, `V` etc. are type parameters. They do not have to be single, upper-case letters - you can use anything that's a valid identifier in Java.

Almost everybody uses single upper-case letters for type parameters - it's a convention that almost everybody follows, so I strongly suggest you do the same.

You could for example just as well do:

```
public class MyClass<Value> {
    Value v;
    setSomeValue(Value val) {
       v=val;
    }

    Value getSomeValue() {
        return v;
    }
 }
```